# find command with two different patterns

Tags: shell, unix, find

I have a huge directory with video files and subtitles, now I usually have 3 different subtiles files which is incorrect.

```
videofilename.srt
videofilename.en.srt
videofilename.sv.srt
```

English subtitles followed by english subtitles (again) and then swedish. Now my video player will not identify all three since it's two different standards (with and without language).

So I want to delete all files that has videofilename.srt but how the heck do I create a find command for that??

```
find . -type f -name '*[^\...]\.srt'
```

Doesn't seems to work.

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `-regex` in `find` to find files without language part:

```
find . -regex '\./[^.]*\.srt$'

./videofilename.srt
```

---

If you want to ignore all `*.en.srt` and `*.sv.srt` then  use:

```
find . -name '*.srt' -not \( -name '*.en.srt' -o -name '*.sv.srt' \)

./videofilename.srt
```

Comment: But if the videofilename contains a . won't that also be triggered then??

Comment: It will only find filename without DOT in it. If `videofilename` can also contain a DOT then you will need to define all the languages you want to ignore.

Comment: Thank you very much. *humble bow*